# Is famous question badge still awarded at 10K views?

Tags: support, badges, specific-question, views

Did "they" stop giving famous question badges?  If not, does 10K views mean less than 10,000 views?

Comment: Which question are you referring to?

Comment: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39166/marginpar-with-options]

Answer (score 9):

In the list view of questions, certain numbers are rounded. Hover over them and you'll see the actual view count:

[image]

Visit the [actual question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39166) and you'll see at the top right of the page:

[image]